# Unable to delete the persistit_tempvol file after Executing sonar Embedded Runner from Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a set of project's on which I need to execute Sonar. Once I execute sonar task and it publishes the result it deletes all the files in the directory .sonartemp except the file persistit_tempvol. This file is locked by Java SE runtime and I am unable to delete this.

The reason I want to delete this file is once it starts executing another project it creates the same file for that project and the data from previous persistit_tempvol is still  in Java Heap. So after I run few projects I actually go OutOfMemory.

I tried increaing the Heap memory, but the number of projects are very high ~100. I don't want to go one by one and execute them. I want to keep doing it in the loop.

I am running sonarrunner 2.4, windows 7, Java 8, sonar ant task 2.3, Sonar Qube 5.1

Here's how I am executing the sonar runner:

```
EmbeddedRunner.create().addProperties(properties)
            .unmask("org.apache.tools.ant").unmask("org.sonar.ant")
            .execute();
```

The properties is the property file of sonar.

I guess I cannot delete this file from sonar as it's locked by by my JVM. Is there a way I can delete this file?

Comment: Can you please update your question to give more details: which operating system, which version of Java, which version of the SonarQube Ant task, ... Also, what do you mean when you say "Executing sonar Embedded Runner from Java": have you developed something specific around the SonarQube Runner?

Comment: May I ask you what you are trying to achieve? Why aren't you just using the standard Ant Task or the standard SQ Runner?

Comment: I am writing an application that does everything starting from source code checkout, generate the property file and the execute the sonar task. This process will execute for ~100 projects and I just want my application to start and let it continue. So I cant run standard SQ runner. I need to execute it via java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForkedRunner.create().addProperties(properties).execute();

That's all I had to do and it is working fine now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't really need to pass Ant objects as extension so I suggest you give a try to ForkedRunner instead of EmbeddedRunner. This would allow you to start with a clean JVM for each analysis.

FYI we are currently working on improving the embedded mode to support running several consecutive analysis without any resource leak (SQ Runner 2.5 + SQ server 5.2).

Comment: So what will happen when I execute 2 threads and both invoke the ForkRunner??

Comment: I guess it will create as many sub process. But I never tested that so feel free to provide feedback.

Comment: So do you have an idea how can I get the StreamConsumer output. So I have  StreamConsumer stdOut = new PrintStreamConsumer(System.out);  and the I set ForkedRunner.create().setStdOut(stdOut) but I want so store the result of this stdOut in my Log4j.

Comment: Just write a custom StreamConsumer and redirect everything to log4j.